# Near Infrared for distance determination

Tags: electromagnetism

Would near-infrared be an efficient frequency to use in determining the distance from the source of the infrared signal to an object, maybe in the range of 5 to 20 meters away?

I need a formula for determining the resolution one could achieve with differing frequencies in a distance-determining scenario, in which, of course, one would be comparing the reflected signal with the original, outgoing signal.

Comment: No more and no less than any other type of radiation that is not being absorbed over that distance. If you need a laser range finder, they can be had for little money in every hardware store and you save yourself a lot of time reinventing the wheel. The resolution of interferometers, on the other hand, is basically dominated by the stability of your optical bench. Sub-nm resolution is simple, sub-atomic resolution a little harder, but not unheard of. The most precise interferometers can measure distances down to a fraction of a nucleus, I believe.

Comment: You should as this in electronics.stackexchange

Comment: Are you interested in resolutions in the micron scale, cm scale, meter scale, etc?

Comment: I had considered some golf range finders a couple of years ago, but found the refresh rate before making a second reading rather slow.  I need to check back now.  And the hardware store devices.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Centimeter scale resolution can work.  And, I will post to the electronics area.  Thanks.

Comment: In 1972 Zeiss used a infrared tachymeter to measure distances in throw/push etc contests in the stadium at the Olympics in Munich.

Comment: This sure sounds like a case of:  "Tell me the problem you are trying to solve; don't tell me you want to solve it." (with thanks to Jim Holtman)